# Arm Rom.ld ,Ram.ld ,scatterfile ,startup.s ,what all these files do?

Tags: arm, atmel

I have programmed avr microcontroller , but new to arm.I just looked a sample code for sam7s64 that comes with winarm.I am confused about these files rom.ld , ram.ld , scatter file , cstartup.s file. I never saw these kind of files when i programmed avr .Please clarify my doubts what each of them file do.

Answer (score 4):

I have even more samples for you to ponder over http://github.com/dwelch67

Assume you have a toolchain that supports a specific instruction set.  Tools often try to support different implementations.  You might have a microcontroller with X amount of flash and Y amount of ram.  One chip might have the ram at a different place than another, etc.  The instruction set may be the same (or itself may have subtle changes) in order for the toolchain to encode some of the instructions it eventually wants to know what your memory layout is.  It is possible to write code for some processors that is purely position independent, in general though that is not necessarily a goal as it has a cost.  tools also tend to have a unix approach to things.  From source language to object file, which doesnt know the memory layout yet, it leaves some holes to be filled in later.  You can get from different languages depending on the toolchain and instruction set, maybe mixing ada and C and other languages that compile to object.  Then the linker needs to combine all of those things.  You as the programmer can and sometimes have to control what goes where.  You want the vector table to be at the right place, you want your entry code perhaps to be at a certain place, you definitely want .data in ram ultimately and .text in flash.

For the gnu tools you tell the linker where things go using a linker script, other toolchains may have other methods.  With gnu ld you can also use the ld command line...the .ld files you are seeing are there to control this.  Now sometimes this is buried in the bowels of the toolchain install, there is a default place where the default linker script will be found, if that is fine then you dont need to craft a linker script and carry it around with the project.  Depending on the tools you were using on the avr, you either didnt need to mess with it (were using assembly, avra or something where you control this with .org or other similar statements) or the toolchain/sandbox took care of it for you, it was buried (for example with the arduino sandbox).  For example if you write a hello world program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( void )
{
   printf("Hello World!\n");
   return(0);
}
```

and compile that on your desktop/laptop

```
gcc hello.c -o hello
```

there was a linker script involved, likely a nasty, scary, ugly one.  But since you are content with the default linker script and layout for your operating system, you dont need to mess with it it just works.  For these microcontrollers where one toolchain can support a vast array of chips and vendors, you start to have to deal with this.  It is a good idea to keep the linker script with the project as you dont know from one machine or person to the next what exact gnu cross compiler they have, it is not difficult to create projects that work on many gnu cross compiler installs if you keep a few things with the project rather than force them into the toolchain.

The other half of this, in particular with the gnu tools an intimate relationship with the linker script is the startup code.  Before your C program is called there are some expectations.  for example the .data is in place and .bss has been zeroed.  For a microcontroller you want .data saved in non volatile memory so it is there when you start your C program, so it needs to be in flash, but it cant run from there as .data is read/write, so before the entry point of the C code is called you need to copy .data from flash to the proper place in ram.  The linker script describes both where in flash to keep .data and where in ram to copy it.  The startup code, which you can name whatever you want startup.s, start.s, crt0.s, etc, gets variables filled in during the link stage so that code can copy .data to ram, can zero out .bss, can set the stack pointer so you have a stack (another item you need for C to work), then that code calls the C entry point.  This is true for any other high level language as well, if nothing else everyone needs a stack pointer so you need some startup code.

If you look at some of my examples you will see me doing linker scripts and startup code for avr processors as well.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to know exactly what the content of each of the files (rom.ld , ram.ld , scatter file , cstartup.s) are in your specific case. However assuming their names are descriptive enough I will give you an idea of what they are intended to do:

1- **rom.ld/ram.ld**: by the files extensions these are "linker scripts". These files tell the linker how where to put each of the memory sections of the object files (see [GNU LD](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/) to learn all about linker scripts and their syntax)

2- **cstartup.s**: Again, from the extension of this file. It appears to be code written in assembly. Generally in this file the software developer will initialize that microcontroller before passing control to the your main application. Examples of actions performed by this file are:

- Setup the ARM vectors
- Configure the oscillator frequency
- Initialize volatile memory
- Call main()

3- **Scatter** : Personally I have never used this file. However it appears to be a file used to control the memory layout of your application and how that is laid out in your micro ([see reference](http://www.keil.com/forum/14954/)). This appears to be a Keil specific file no different from any other linker script.

Comment: Scatter loading is an armlink feature; not specifically Keil.